# Google Sheets - Using conditional formatting to light up names on a list if they appear in a separate list

Tags: google-sheets

So I created a massive list of possible names for a project that’s on sheet A, and takes up the whole sheet. On a separate tabbed sheet, there’s a much shorter list that contains used names. I want to make the names on sheet A light up only if they appear on sheet B. Is this possible, and if so, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` formula to highlight any cell if the cell value match the value on other sheet:

```
=match($A2,$C:$C,0)
```

[image]

To perform cross sheet reference, you will need `indirect` method, here is the same formula but referring from sheet2:

```
=match($A2,indirect("sheet2!$C:$C"),0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried this out and it works with a single column on the same sheet, but it doesn't seem to work for what I'm trying to use it for. The list I'm highlighting are from Sheet1!B2:DO369 (yes, long, I know) and I'm scanning for them in Sheet2!A1:A500.

Comment: Check my edited answer, it is working but require other formula.